# How do I control computer mouse with M5StickC Plus?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, adafruit

I recently purchased the M5StickC Plus and wish to control computer cursor with it. However I'm having trouble compling the program.

Here is the error message when I installed the mouse library:

```
#include "HID.h"
^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Multiple libraries were found for "Mouse.h"
Used: C:\Users\Jerry\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Mouse
Not used: C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Mouse
exit status 1
```

If I uninstall the library it looks like this:

```
#include "HID.h"
^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

exit status 1
```

What seems to be the problem here and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The M5StickC Plus only provides serial communication via USB. It cannot emulate a USB HID.

You need an MCU that provides a real USB interface to run this example.

But you can implement a bluetooth mouse and keyboard if it's any comfort to you :)